# read multiple CSV files from a Google Drive folder and append then in a single one in R

Tags: r, google-drive-api, tidyverse, google-drive-shared-drive

[This is how csv_file object created below looks like on the console panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO5Rv.png)I have several csv files in a google drive that I would like to append as one data frame witout downloading those files in my local computer.

Usually when I call multiple files from my local computer I used the following code, where list.files put all those csv files in a list and then map_df makes one dataframe from all those files in the list.

```
hourly.files <- list.files(path = "Folder_path_withCSV_files", 
                pattern = "*.csv", 
                full.names = T)%>%
  map_df(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c"))) #makes one dataframe
```

I want to do the same but in this case the files are many more and are in a shared google drive.
Using google drive:

```
folder_url <- "https://drive.google.com/folder/directory" #path to the files
folder <- drive_get(as_id(folder_url)) #folder id
csv_files <- drive_ls(folder, type = "csv") #makes a list of with all the csv files
```

Then, I tried to create a dataframe with the following code:
`create.df <- map_df(~read_csv(csv_files$id, col_types = cols(.default = "c")))` 
but get this error below:
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

As I said, I do not want to download those files in my local computer because there are too many and my collaborators will me modifying the csv files in the google folder constantly so downloading every time is something I want to avoid.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly (I don't know what csv_files looks like. But When you run a map command you need to first have the argument of what to map over. Something more like create.df <- map_df(csv_files, ~read_csv(.x$id, col_types = cols(.default = "c"))) should work, where .x stands in for each element in csv_files

Comment: Hi John Franchak. Thank you your suggestion. I added a picture of how the csv_file object looks like (dribble with ID). I tried but I got this error                   
 Error in .x$id : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: if you want to read the files in csv_files$id, i don't think you can use read_csv. read_csv can read from disk or from url, but if you're interacting with google drive through the googledrive api you need to use one of those package functions (which can handle a google drive id). since you're only using sheets, you might want to use the googlesheets4 package.

Comment: Thank you @JohnFranchak. I will look into that package and see if it work for me, because I am not really using googlesheet , those are csv files stored in a shared google drive. I will update this post if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this may work for anyone who may be interested-

Using `googledrive` functions you can locate your folder and the information about the files you wish to access. You then use `drive_read_string` to bring the simplified data into R where it can then be read using `read.csv` and added to a matrix.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(googledrive)

folder_url <- "YourfolderURL" #locate your folder
folder <- drive_get(as_id(folder_url)) #get the folder ID
csv_files <- drive_ls(folder, type = "csv") #specify the files type you're interested in. In this instance .csv's

get_file_fxn<- function(x){ #wrapped into a function for downloading multiple files
  tmp<- drive_read_string(x) #converts the stored .csv file to a string 
  tmp_df<-tmp %>% read.csv(text= ., header = F) #reads the string and turns it back into a .csv file within R
  tmp_df #print the output
}

data<- bind_rows(lapply(csv_files$id,get_file_fxn)) # Uses the newly created function to bind the output to rows of a matrix
```

Not very elegant perhaps, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error. Try -

```
library(tidyverse)

create.df <- map_df(csv_files$id, ~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c")))
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried and I got this error:                                                   `Error: '1I_-UCSBc7kSO0i0Z_V3_HXzWmPFESpXX' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/XXXYYY/Documents')`                                                                                                                   It is looking for the file in my local directory, but I honestly do not understand why if I am still interacting with google drive

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read file directly from your google drive you should download [Google Drive for desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) first and then go to your shared google drive folder and copy and paste the path into your code

This url you are using is for your browser like Chrome and will not work.

```
folder_url <- "https://drive.google.com/folder/directory" #path to the files
```

Open the shared google drive folder via google drive for desktop tool and use that url path in your code. It will work.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, because this code it will be use by other people I have been asked to use googledrive api and not the google drive desktop because not many people may have the capability to downloaded google drive desktop. I did tried as you suggested and it worked after i downloaded. I will keep looking and once I have a solution I will update the post.